# Spyder won't run my code - Fresh install and a simple script

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a fresh reinstall of Spyder 5.1.5 via Anaconda. This is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I have a really simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar 23 11:24:01 2022

@author: me
"""

print("This is a test")
print ("This is a second test")
```

The code runs in normal mode (F5, runfile(), etc.) and at the command line.
Spyder does not run this code in debug mode (Ctrl+F5, debugfile()). There is no error message:
[image: Screenshot of Spyder IDE]

The ----> in the console leads me to believe it's in debug mode, but the "Run current line" and "Continue until Breakpoint" commands do nothing.

As the issue is just with debug mode, I believe the problem is in Spyder somewhere. Does anyone have any tips??

Comment: It does... Thank you for the pointer!
(this next bit is rhetorical, and not directed at you personally!)
Why, oh why, does updating anaconda and associated programs not actually update anaconda and associated programs!!! Grr!!